# iOS : Issue in submitting app to appStore / adhoc deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipa

i am trying to submit app to appStore and also alternatively trying to create ***ipa*** for ***adhoc*** deployment. i have already tried many solutions but nothing changed. I have already generated new ***certificates*** and ***provisioning profiles*** but it always shows me this error message:

> ***You already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate***
>   You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center, but it is not installed locally. if uour sigining identity is installed on another Mac, You can export on that Mac and import it on this Mac.

Please help me out to get rid of this issue

Comment: Are You using provisioning profiles for Distribution(APP Store) ? There are two type of distribution PP ADHoc And APP Store. Use APP store PP for Upload.

Comment: have you installed the distribution certificate in you development mac keychain? if not Download from developer account and install the certificates

Comment: Yes i have installed them in my mac keychain @Sujaina

Answer (score 1):

you are missing your Distribution Certificates Private key on this computer. If you have another machine that can codesign distribution builds, then transfer the certificates and profiles from that machine using the workflow discussed in the "Transferring iOS Certificates and Profiles to another Machine (Exporting and Importing Certificates and Profiles)" section above, otherwise follow the instructions below (as appropriate for the type of app you are creating).

if you revoke your iOS Distribution certificate, then Xcode will recreate your private key and request a new Distribution Certificate for you. See the steps in the Revoking Certificates section of the App Distribution.

use this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW26)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make an .ipa without valid Developer's account, please follow the next steps:

1) xcodebuild clean -workspace /Users/JohnDoe/Projects/TheApp/TheApp.xcworkspace -configuration Release -scheme TheApp

2) xcodebuild archive -workspace /Users/JohnDoe/Projects/TheApp/TheApp.xcworkspace -scheme TheApp -archivePath ~/TheApp.xcarchive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO

3) cd ~

4) xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath TheApp.xcarchive -exportPath ~/TheApp.ipa

After the final step the .ipa is waiting for you in your home directory!